# Beta decay (nuclear physics) fermi kurie plot

Tags: nuclear-physics

what type of beta decay does that fermi kurie plot represents? [image]

Comment: Doesn't it say at the bottom of the figure?

Comment: no it doesn't show any information

Comment: Sure it does. Rob even included it in half his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a [Fermi-Kurie plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#Kurie_plot) of allowed $0^+\to0^+$ decay in $^{66}$Ga.  The horizontal scale is the relativistic total energy $W = T_\mathrm e + m_\mathrm e c^2$, in units of $m_\mathrm e c^2$.
The deviation of the data from the straight line at low energy arises from the scattering of low-energy electrons within the radioactive source.
That particular plot was [published in 1963](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.129.1782), but for more explanation you might try a modern introductory nuclear physics textbook, like Krane.

Comment: thanks for explanation ..what i understood that it represents beta negative as you said low energy electrons ?